# AD9833 Function Generator - Poor square waveform

Tags: function-generator

I have built a function generator using an AD9833 board, using the schematics found [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-DIY-waveform-generator-analog-devices-ad9833-ATmega328p/). The circuit seems to work well, but the square waveform that it outputs isn't great and there is some overshoot in the rise and fall of each transition. I was wondering if anyone can suggest what the problem might be? I know it's difficult to say but any suggestions on how to fix this would be welcome. Below are a bunch of pics from my scope and a photo of the build.

Here is the sine output, which seems good:
[image]

Here is the noise in the negative transition of the square wave at 1kHz:
[image]

Here is the noise in the positive transition:
[image]

Here are two pictures of the square wave at 500kHz, the first with the gain turned up, the second with it set lower:
[image]
[image]

Photo of the build:
[image]

EDIT:

As requested, here are the waveforms as measured at the output of the op-amp. Interestingly the p-p voltage doesn't seem to vary with the output frequency. Here is the waveform at 1kHz:

[image]

And at 200kHz:

[image]

Here is a picture of the power board:

[image]

Comment: Did you check your 10x scope probe compensation? Or are you driving directly the BNC connector with the inductive loop wiring instead of coaxial cable? What you show in the scope photos looks pretty normal for the type of loose wiring construction I see in the picture. Fast edges (as in the square wave) will rapidly degrade if put through a bandwidth-limited system like the one in the photo, causing those ringing effects.

Comment: Hi @MarkU thanks for your reply. I have calibrated my probe for 10x so I think that is not the issue. Yes you're probably right that my sketchy wiring is to blame. When you say "driving the BNC connector" are you referring to the black and red wires I have connected to the board and soldered to the back of the BNC connector? Should that be replaced with coaxial cable?

Comment: you could at least not have the pair of red and black paralleled the whole run (capacitively coupled).

Comment: @dandavis yes, I think I will disconnect the BNC connector and probe the output of the op-amp directly to see if that is the problem. At least then I will have reduced the number of possible culprits. Thanks for your input, I'll let you know how it goes tonight.

Comment: Did not forget that many HF devices have a 50 Ohm Load?

Comment: @Antonio51 hi Antonio, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @MarkU I probed the output of the op-amp directly and, while the amount of ringing at the transitions was smaller, it was still present and significant. With a 5V amplitude square wave the p-p voltage was around 6.5V at the op-amp. I also noticed that the DC lines (+-12V and +5V) have a fair amount of noise on them - around 200mV according to my scope. Do you think this could also be an issue? I could try powering it from a better supply rather than my cobbled together mains PSU.

Comment: @Jaska Sorry. It is not 50 Ohm load, but AD9833 has a 200 Ohm load on "board" (verified on the datasheet). What is the wave directly on the output pin?

Comment: @Antonio51 I have made an edit to the post to show the waveforms.

Comment: For the overshoot, perhaps a little capacitor between pin 2 and pin 6 of LM318 (1 to 10 pF). Will try to simulate...

Comment: Hi @Antonio51, did you manage to have a look at the simulation? I have been doing a bit more reading and it seems other people might be having this "ringing" issue with the AD9833. I will try some small caps across pins 2 and 6 and see if it helps at all.

Comment: I think that the ringing does not come from AD9833, but with LM318. Tried to simulate with gain=~1, with 1-3 pF between 2 and 3 of LM318, or/and 1-10pF between 2-6. It is ok, but "rise time" is bigger. The problem seems to be with the pot2 gain. To be searched: other means setting "gain", and another opamp.

Comment: At gain = 1 (!) and with opamp LM6164 (or "some"), it is better. Rise time= 10 ns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems really the "gain" set by pot2 between pin 2-6 of the opamp.
For variable gain, rather use an attenuator, and amplifier at fix gain.
However, use coax when needed, short wires ... and also PCB, not breadboard at high frequencies.

Simulated this with LM6164, but gain set by input resistor (1k-10k).

[image]

[image]

Added pictures for non-inverting circuitry. Note the overshoot if gain=1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate you looking into this for me, it's very helpful. I will try what you suggest and see if it helps. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Keep me informed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I can't find that LM6164 in stock anywhere - is it an absolete part? Is there another Op-Amp with similar spec that you'd recommend?

Comment: I found the LM7171 - perhaps this would be suitable? I can get it from Mouser and it seems to be quite high spec.

Comment: Seems ok. Little overshoot as LM6164 in simulation.

Comment: I am just putting your circuit together - I missed previosuly the "X2" next to the op-amp in the schematic above. What exactly does it mean? Should I be using two op-amps in parallel or something? I only ordered one!

Comment: Also, in my original schematic the output from the AS9833 goes to the non-inverting input of the op-amp, whereas in yours it goes to the inverting input - is there a way to wire your circuit up to the non-inverting input so I don't have to make too many changes to my circuitboard? Thanks again

Comment: Yes. Ok. I used the inverting circuitry. Using the non-inverting circuitry is ok also. Just keep the same "fix" resistors on the - feedback way. I will add simulation for the non-inverting.

Comment: Sorry. I did not answer at your question about "X2" ... it is "only" the "label" of the opamp... :-)

Comment: Thank you for the updated simulations. I can't see what the difference between the two cases is though (except for the different cap values) - all the resistors have the same value? Is R3 still the potentiometer that controls the output level, as in the first pair of simulations you posted?

Comment: Also, what simulator are you using? I can't find one that has the LM7171 (or 7121) in it. I would like to do the simulations myself as well for the learning exercise.

Comment: I add in answer. R3 control gain, always >1 ... Pot is not the better thing to use in these designs :-)  microcap v12 here http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with the circuits and let you know what I come up with